# Capturing a video on android and playing it on iPhone

Tags: android, iphone

**I am capturing a video on my android device, the video format is `.mp4`.
When i'm trying to play the video on an iPhone device the video just won't play but any other video that was captured on the iPhone device plays just fine.**

Is there any type of video and audio `encoding` that is both suitable for android and iPhone?

This is the Java code I set the Audio/video encoders :

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try just like:

```
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
```

Comment: Yea thanks, figured that out as well from the android dev reference.